# Cant get pills in bootstrap 3 to function correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I try to click on a pill, the page stays on the first pill and refuses to change. I am using the latest version of bootstrap. Is there anything that i could do to fix it?

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#Home" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#About" data-toggle="pill">About</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#items" data-toggle="pill">items</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#Things" data-toggle="pill">things</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#stuff" data-toggle="pill">stuff</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#other" data-toggle="pill">other</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane jumbotron active">
                    <h1>Generic</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Blah.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">blah</a></p>
                </div>
                <div id="About" class="tab-pane">
                    <h3>Section A</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="items" class="tab-pane">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="Things" class="tab-pane">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="stuff" class="tab-pane">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="other" class="tab-pane">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>\
```

Comment: Please put your code into an interactive demo using an online editor such as http://codepen.io/ so that the community can help solve your issues. Most of the time you will figure out the solution to your issue in the time it takes to set up the demo.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, [you just need to import the bootstrap javascript file.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn)

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a [link to it working perfectly on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx7apemu/).